# How to stop pycharm auto format code after pasted?

Tags: formatting, pycharm

### In brief

I want to turn off code auto-formation in PyCharm

### In full

I often get my comments auto-formatted

from

```
#my comment
```

to

```
# my comment with space inserted
```

I want to turn this off and found [via google](https://www.google.com.vn/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20stop%20pycharm%20auto%20format%20code%20after%20pasted) this [article from JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206596255-How-to-disable-auto-formatting-on-paste-); though I cannot find the guided option in my PyCharm as snapshots below.

I'm using

```
PyCharm 2016.2.3
Build #PY-162.1967.10, built on September 7, 2016
```

[image]

Comment: At times I wish the JetBrains developers would switch to decaf.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

look under Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys -> Reformat On Paste and set to 'None'. see screen.

[image]

UPDATE:  looks like the suggestion above didn't work, but i did find another editor setting (python-specific) that will auto-format your code. see attached screenshot. you can get to the setting via:

`Preferences->Editor->Code Style->Python` near the bottom. deselect the `after #` setting and try again. this worked for me -- it allowed me to paste the string you had above without having it auto-formatted. HTH

[image]

Comment: I have this option to None and still get the issue. Any ideas @@? Seem like a bug to me.

Comment: what do your settings under the `smart keys` prefs pane show (like the info i screen-captured above)?

Comment: Same screen as yours.

Comment: updated the answer above with change to diff option, which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: One issue with this answer (the second part): it doesn't remove reformatting, it just changes the default you reformat to. Meaning, now it will always reformat to remove any spaces after `#`. I still haven't found a solution that just preserves the format of what you are pasting (pretty annoying that it's this difficult to get around PyCharm's "helping hands").

Answer (score 4):

With PyCharm 2016.3, just use menu command `Edit - Paste Simple`

Comment: Now it's `Edit` - `Paste` - `Paste as Plain Text`, aka Ctrl-Shift-Alt-V

Answer (score 4):

`[File > Settings > Keymap]`, search for `Paste`, right click on "Paste as Plain Text", and reassign the key `Ctrl-C` to it.

Tested with PyCharm 2021.3.2, should work in the latest.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right click - Paste without formatting, this did the trick for me.

Comment: For the latest version of PyCharm (2021.2.3), it's called "Paste as Plain Text".

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was trying to paste a line of regular non-code text and then use the comment shortcut to comment out the pasted text. PyCharm auto-formats the text to be one line for each word. (It breaks on any white space.) I also only have this problem when I paste on an indented line

The workaround is to always type `#` and then paste. Or Edit - Paste - Paste as Plain Text. I still consider it a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to "Reformat on paste" setting to NONE (Editor || General || Smart Keys),
you have to also set "Smart ident pasted lines" under Editor || General || Smart Keys || Python

[Smart ident pasted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLfhr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to File>Setting>Save Actions and turn off all actions. Hit apply and you are good to go.[See the picture for more info.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpGTw.png)

Comment: That's a pretty radical solution for such a simple task. It's like if someone asked "how to lose weight" and you answering "by not eating".